# Time series and legend with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Thi is my data:

```
x <- c("22-01-16","26-01-16","28-01-16","01-02-16","05-02-16","16-02-16","17-03-16","18-03-16","04-04-16","05-04-16","06-04-16","08-04-16")
y <- c(97.14,75,54.44,70.45,110.56,66.3,178.76,171.90,419.41,424,518.63,242.17)
z <- c("ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP","ADCP")
```

So I make the dataframe

```
Datos <- data.frame(x)
Datos$Caudal <- y
Datos$Tipo <- z
Datos$Fecha <- as.Date(Datos$x, "%d-%m-%y")
```

and plot using ggplot2

```
Serie_Caudal <-
ggplot(Datos, aes(Fecha, Caudal)) +
geom_line(size=1, colour="red") +
geom_point(shape=23,size=1, colour="blue",fill = "blue") +
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week",labels = date_format("%d/%b"))+
xlab("Fecha") + ylab(bquote('Caudal ('*m^3~s^-1*')')) +
ggtitle("Caudales Diarios (01-06/2016)")
Serie_Caudal
```

I try to plot a legend but i can´t the way, i try use `Melt` but my data change in a way i can´t plot. Also try `scale_fill_manual` but the legend don´t show up. I want to know if there is a way to put a legend manualy.

The legend must show a blue point and ADCP

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. Do you want to learn how to plot legends?

Comment: Yes, can you outline what you are trying to plot as a legend?

Comment: What exactly do you want in the legend? ggplot only creates legends for mapped aesthetics. It would help if you could be more clear on what the desired output is here.

Comment: sorry hope explain better now

Comment: @AnesG your question doesn't allows us to reproduce the problem. To get a legend, you need to map something within aes(), also ADCP has only one variable, what legend could come out of it?

Comment: What about `Serie_Caudal + geom_line(size=1, aes(colour="foo")) + scale_color_manual(values = c("foo"="orange"), name = "bar") `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows only a blue dot.

```
ggplot(aes(Fecha, Caudal, colour = "ADCP"), data = Datos) +  
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(shape=23,size=1,color="blue",fill = "blue") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("ADCP"="blue"),name = "") +
  geom_line(color="red", size=1) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week",labels = date_format("%d/%b")) +
  xlab("Fecha") + ylab(bquote('Caudal ('*m^3~s^-1*')')) +
  ggtitle("Caudales Diarios (01-06/2016)")
```

[image]

Comment: Why use two geom_point?, which data represente the first geom_point?